# AttributeError: 'QAction' object has no attribute 'setShortcutVisibleInContextMenu'

Tags: python, pyqt5, spyder

I am using Spyder on Windows.

These are my python version and modules:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> python --version
Python 3.9.10
PS C:\Windows\system32> pip list
Package            Version
------------------ ---------
imageio            2.18.0
joblib             1.1.0
networkx           2.8
numpy              1.22.3
packaging          21.3
Pillow             9.1.0
pip                22.0.4
pyparsing          3.0.8
PyQt5              5.15.6
PyQt5-Qt5          5.15.2
PyQt5-sip          12.10.1
PySide6            6.3.0
PySide6-Addons     6.3.0
PySide6-Essentials 6.3.0
PyWavelets         1.3.0
scikit-image       0.19.2
scikit-learn       1.0.2
scipy              1.8.0
setuptools         58.1.0
shiboken6          6.3.0
threadpoolctl      3.1.0
tifffile           2022.4.28
```

This is my code related to this error:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget,QInputDialog,QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *

self.actionOpen_Source.setShortcutVisibleInContextMenu(True)
```

This is the error message:

```
File "T:\OOP-2 Lab Final\oop2labfinal.py", line 393, in setupUi
    self.actionOpen_Source.setShortcutVisibleInContextMenu(True)

AttributeError: 'QAction' object has no attribute 'setShortcutVisibleInContextMenu'
```

Comment: [`setShortcutVisibleInContextMenu`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#shortcutVisibleInContextMenu-prop) was introduced in Qt 5.10, ensure that you have at least that version in your Spyder environment: `from PyQt5 import QtCore; print(QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR)`.

Comment: my qt at version  5.15.6

Comment: @H.C.AslanÖZEN Check your ***Spyder*** environment, not your system environment.

Comment: I solved the problem even though I didn't fully understand it. I installed spyder before anaconda. I deleted spyder and downloaded it from anaconda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem even though I didn't fully understand it. I had downloaded spyder before downloading anaconda. I deleted Spyder and downloaded it from anaconda and the problem was solved.

Comment: As already said, you need to ensure about the library versions used in your environment. If you're using anaconda, you must check the versions used on *that* environment.